# Is JavaScript execution context preserved between page visiting/reloading?

Tags: javascript, execution

Is JavaScript execution context preserved between page visiting/reloading?

I load data and want to cache it, but user may follow links or submit forms. So I lose any JS object after a new page loaded?

Comment: Yes you do. Whenever you go away from the current page, the JavaScript objects created on that page are lost. You can either store them using `localstorage`, which is not supported by all the browsers (Check: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) and use them later or use AJAX to store the objects on your server side and load them somehow on the pages you require them on.

Comment: Cookies are supported by more browsers than localstorage

Comment: Maybe `sessionStorage` in your case is better.

Comment: Thank for answers! +1. Are there any standard or technical agreement that describe context losing behaviour?